# Sending Email To Thousands of Candidates on New Job Submission - Wp Job manager

Tags: php, wordpress, mailgun

I am using MailGun API to send Batch email. I am using WP_Query to build query which is actually the list of emails which have to be notified on New Job Postings.

These emails are extracted on the basis of matching category. Like if Job is Posted in Category A,B and Z then the Resumes/Candidates of having Category A,B and Z (at least any of these matching Categories)should be notified.

Problem lies in MailGun Batch Email which has a limit of 1000.

I have tried with below code and looks like it is working but not completely. It should show more data. And I need suggestions if it can be done in more better way.

I am using MailGun API just because it has the ability to send 1000 emails/sessions so if we use wp-mail then the page will die or database is not that much efficient to handle.

**I can confidently say that my code is poorly written** :-D

Please see below my code and suggest for improvements. Also this code I have added in directly Plugin's template file job-submitted.php

**Here is the code:**

```
      $job_term_list = wp_get_post_terms($job->ID, 'job_listing_category', array("fields" => "names"));

        $job_skills = implode(',',$job_term_list);

        $tax_terms = get_terms('resume_function', array('hide_empty' => true));

        foreach($tax_terms as $term_single) $resume_cat_name[] = $term_single->name; 

        $result=array_intersect($resume_cat_name,$job_term_list);

        $fin_result=implode(',',$result);  //Matched posted skills

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args = array(
        'post_type'              => array( 'resume' ),
        'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
        'has_password'           => false,
        'nopaging'               => false,
        'paged'                  => $paged,
        'posts_per_page'         => '10',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'    => false,
        'order'                  => 'DESC',
        'orderby'                => 'title',
        'resume_function' => $fin_result,

    );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$total = $query->found_posts;

if ($total < 1000){
 $paged = 1;
 $post_per_page = '1000';
}
 else{
 $paged = ceil($total / 1000) ;
 $post_per_page = $paged.'000';
 }
$args_two = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'resume' ),
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'has_password'           => false,
    'nopaging'               => false,
    'paged'                  => $paged,
    'posts_per_page'         => $post_per_page,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'    => false,
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                => 'title',
    'resume_function' => $fin_result,

);

$query_two = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() OR $query_two->have_posts() ) {


    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        $post_id = get_the_ID();

        $candidate_name = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_candidate_name', true );
        $candidate_email = get_post_meta($post_id, '_candidate_email', true);



        if($candidate_email){

*** HERE I WILL ADD MAILGUN CURL FUNCTIONALITY FOR BATCH EMAIL ****



        }

    }

    while ( $query_two->have_posts() ) {
        $query_two->the_post();

        $post_id = get_the_ID();

        $candidate_name = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_candidate_name', true );

        if($candidate_email){
       *** HERE ALSO I WILL ADD MAILGUN CURL FUNCTIONALITY FOR BATCH EMAIL ****
        }

    }

}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: probably better for the code review SE

Comment: What is SE? And why I get Negative Rank

Comment: StackExchange - StackOverflow is just one rose of the beautiful bouquet that is StackExchange - google code review SE and it should come up. I voted down. Questions asking to make code better do not belong on SO

Comment: @vanurag "SE" is StackExchange, the network of sites you're on. Code Review is over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but read the rules there.

Comment: This is not actually code review. This is my query. I need help on achieving

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for code review.

Comment: from your question `Please see below my code and suggest for improvements. Also this code I have added in directly Plugin's template file job-submitted.php` -> that's a code review

Comment: @vanurag You stated "I have tried with below code and looks like it is working so far but need suggestions if it can be done in more better way." That puts it in the realm of code review.

Comment: Yes . It is showing result but only few not full result

Comment: I am Editing the question

Answer (score 0):

Mailgun simply isn't the right tool for the job - no matter how efficient your code.

Mailgun is designed for transactional emails - and what you're looking to do is closer to broadcast mails. Have a look at the Mailchimp APIs, within which you can create dynamic groups of recipients programmatically - and then send an email to a list, rather than attempting to hit the Mailgun API repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding answer a bit late but in case if anyone needed it. Here is what I did:

I simply added false flag in database table for sending mail and then using CRON I am sending email once in a day by checking the mail send flag FALSE against each job ID.

After sending mail successfully, I again updated the table column flag to TRUE(Mail Sent).

In the &args, I have also updated

```
'posts_per_page'         => '10',
```

To

```
'posts_per_page'         => $Total_Job_Count,
```

Where $Total_Job_Count calculates the total number of post for the custom post type.

Doing this fetches all the result.